# JavaScript - spread and rest syntax to remove specific property from object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2018

I have an object as follows :

```
let obj = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
```

I would like to delete a specific property by calling a method that takes as parameter the name of the property to delete

```
removeProperty(obj, propertyName) {
  let { propertyName, _, ...result } = obj
  return result
}
```

the problem is that this method only works when we write the name of the property directly in the syntax spead, like: `let { bar, _, ...result } = obj` .But it does not work by passing it as a parameter, because the syntax spead creates it as a new variable

how can we do that, with another solution if possible except the `omit` of lodash

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use computed properties in destructuring:

```js
let obj = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
function removeProperty(obj, propertyName) {
  let { [propertyName]: _, ...result } = obj
  return result
}
console.log(removeProperty(obj, 'foo'));
```

This will assign the property with the name of the value `propertyName` to a throwaway variable and essentially remove that key. See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring).

Comment: Why does setting it to an underscore remove it?

Comment: @manley13 It doesn't need to be. The underscore could be anything. It's just convention to use an underscore as a dummy variable in programming since it's not used.

Comment: Is this possible if propertyName was an array? Trying to remove multiple computed properties from an object at once

Comment: @MarcSlothEastman Not that I know of. You can use a loop and `delete` like in the other answer or filter out keys: `Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !forbiddenKeys.includes(key)).reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: obj[key] }), {})` though it's quite a sore on the eyes. It'd be more clear to do the former.

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative to `destructuring` would be to use `delete`. The following solution reduces time-complexity by about 35% compared to `destructuring` (in Desktop Chrome)

#### Solution

```
let obj = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
function removeProperty(obj, propertyName) {
  let newObj = {...obj};
  delete newObj[propertyName];
  return newObj;
}
console.log(removeProperty(obj, 'foo'));
```

#### Performance Test

https://jsperf.com/so53753276

The results vary depending upon the browser used. The results are rather intriguing. Desktop Safari `destructuring` outperforms `delete`, but Desktop Chrome out performs all numbers from Desktop Safari.

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Browser | delete    | destructure |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| Chrome  | 3,229,791 | 1,993,256   |
| Safari  | 1,186,679 | 1,872,396   | 
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

The results on iOS are less surprising, as Chrome is just really Safari under the hood.

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Browser | delete    | destructure |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| Chrome  | 1,146,496 | 1,785,551   |
| Safari  | 1,182,067 | 1,793,772   | 
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Interestingly on Safari iOS my code runs faster. Cloning then `delete`ing is 43% slower.

Comment: @Li357 It does indeed appear that your solution is the most performant overall when weighted against all browsers; however, Desktop Chrome does shockingly outperform everyone when it comes to `delete`

Answer (score 4):

```
values = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'hello world',
    vehicle: 'car',
    time: '3.30 pm',
    date: '02 MAR 1990',
};

const { time, date, ...rest } = values;

now ***...rest*** contains the object values of {
    id: 1,
    name: 'hello world',
    vehicle: 'car',
};
```